# Lombok newbie with JSTL - how is it supposed to work?

Tags: java, jstl, lombok

I have a JSP using JSTL to access a list of instances of a bean called `Month`

```
<c:forEach var="month" items="${months}">
    <option value="${month.index}">${month.label}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Until recently, the `Month` class had all its Getters and Setters declared explicitly; but then I heard about project Lombok and wondered if it might be applicable here.  So, using Lombok's annotation I define the `Month` class as:

```
public @Data class Month{
    private Integer index;
    private String label;
    private boolean selected;  
}
```

I expected this to 'automagically' generate the Getters and Setters so that JSTL could do its thing, but when I visit the page, I get an exception on the server `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'index' not found on type com.company.package.Month`

Am I mistaken about how to apply Lombok in this scenario?

Comment: What IDE are you using, what compiler? Does the code creating the Month *object* work? Can you call the getter from a Java program?

Comment: Eclipse/ Tomcat/ Java 1.7.0_45-b18.  The same code works if I declare explicit getters on the Month bean.  If i only use the Lombok annotation and  write a program that calls month.setIndex(1) I get a compiler error `undefined method`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in the About Eclipse screen if lombok is installed correctly. On the bottom line, it should say something like"

```
Lombok v1.16.8 "Candid Duck" is installed. https://projectlombok.org/
```

If it doesn't, please check eclipse.ini, and look if in `vmargs` the agent is provided: `-javaagent:lombok.jar`.

- Yes: Launch `eclipse.exe` directly, not using a shortcut. It it works, modify the shortcut to add the correct `vmargs`
- No: Stop Eclipse, install lombok into Eclipse using `java -jar lombok.jar`, or double-click the jar file, and start Eclipse. Do not use `restart` since it doesn't pick up modifications in the ini-file.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.